# Bash variable assign doesn't work

Tags: bash

http://pastebin.com/P46B7Zcy

```
#!/bin/bash
KONIEC=0
WYSZ="Wyszukiwarka"
NAZWA=""
KATALOG="."
ZAWARTOSC=""
ROZMIAR=""
CZAS=""
USER=""
SZUKAJ=""
LICZ=0
WYNIK=""
POMOC=0
while [ $KONIEC -ne 8 ]; do
    informacja="Tytuł: $NAZWA\nKatalog: $KATALOG\nRozmiar: $ROZMIAR\nArtysta: $USER\nRok wydania: $CZAS\nContent type: $ZAWARTOSC\nRezultat: $SZUKAJ";
    menu=("Tytuł" "Katalog" "Rozmiar" "Artysta" "Rok wydania" "Content type" "KONIEC")
    opt=$(zenity --list --height 360 --title=$WYSZ --text="$informacja" --cancel-label "WYSZUKAJ" --ok-label "Wybierz opcję" --column="Menu główne" "${menu[@]}")

    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        find $KATALOG -type f -iname \*.mp3 | while read -r line ; do   
            name=${line##*/}
                POMOC=0     
                if [ -n "$NAZWA" ]; then
                    POLECENIE=' '$NAZWA
                    TYTUL=$(id3info $name | grep TIT2 | cut -d ":" -f 2)
                    if [ "$POLECENIE" == "$TYTUL" ];then
                        POMOC=1
                    else
                        POMOC=2
                    fi              
                fi
                echo $POMOC
                if [ $POMOC -ne 2 ];then 
                    if [ -n "$USER" ]; then
                        POLECENIE=' '$USER
                        TYTUL=$(id3info $name | grep TPE1 | cut -d ":" -f 2)
                        if [ "$POLECENIE" == "$TYTUL" ]
                        then
                            POMOC=1
                        else
                            POMOC=2
                        fi              
                    fi
                fi
                if [ $POMOC -ne 2 ];then 
                    if [ -n "$ZAWARTOSC" ]; then
                        POLECENIE=' '$ZAWARTOSC
                        TYTUL=$(id3info $name | grep TCON | cut -d ":" -f 2)
                        if [ "$POLECENIE" == "$TYTUL" ]
                        then
                            POMOC=1
                        else
                            POMOC=2
                        fi              
                    fi
                fi
                if [ $POMOC -ne 2 ];then 
                    if [ -n "$CZAS" ]; then
                        POLECENIE=' '$CZAS
                        TYTUL=$(id3info $name | grep TYER | cut -d ":" -f 2)
                        if [ "$POLECENIE" == "$TYTUL" ]
                        then
                            POMOC=1
                        else
                            POMOC=2
                        fi              
                    fi
                fi

                if [ $POMOC -eq 1 ]; then
                    WYNIK=$name
                    echo "$WYNIK" # Line 72
                fi  


        done
        echo "$WYNIK" # Line 77
        zenity --info --title $WYSZ --text "$WYNIK"
    fi

    case "$opt" in

        "${menu[0]}" )
            NAZWA=$(zenity --entry --title $WYSZ --text "Podaj tytuł:" --height 120)
            ;;
            "${menu[1]}" )

            KATALOG=$(zenity --entry --title $WYSZ --text "Podaj katalog:" --height 120)
            ;;
            "${menu[2]}" )

            ROZMIAR=$(zenity --entry --title $WYSZ --text "Podaj rozmiar pliku:" --height 120)
            ;;
            "${menu[3]}" )

            USER=$(zenity --entry --title $WYSZ --text "Podaj wykonawce:" --height 120)
            ;;
            "${menu[4]}" )

            CZAS=$(zenity --entry --title $WYSZ --text "Podaj rok wydania:" --height 120)
            ;;
            "${menu[5]}" )

            ZAWARTOSC=$(zenity --entry --title $WYSZ --text "Podaj content type:" --height 120)
            ;;
            "${menu[6]}" )  

            KONIEC=8
            esac


        done
```

Echo in line 72 pritns something when WYNIK is not empty, but then in line 77 it prints nothing every time, why?

Comment: Please post a [*minimal* example](http://www.sscce.org) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: This is BashFAQ #24: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 0):

When you pipe into a loop, that loop runs in a subshell.

Instead of:

```
... | while read; do
done
```

run:

```
while read; do
done < <(...)
```

...which puts the `...` alone into the subshell, and puts the contents of the loop into the main shell.

---

As an aside, when using `find`, be sure you use `-print0` and `IFS= read -r -d ''` so names with newline literals can't break your code. That is:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  : something with "$filename"
done < <(find ... -print0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are creating a sub shell with find|while  The changes in a sub shell are lost in the parent shell.

Use

```
while read -r line; do
   commands
done < <(find command)
```

Answer (score 0):

`WYNIK` is first assigned an empty string.

The reason why the line 77 prints empty string is because`bash` creates a subshell to execute `| while ... done` block, as it does for all pipelines.

Remember that any modification of the variable in the subshell has no impact in the parent shell.

The subshell inherites variables. When `WYNIK` is assigned a value, line 72 can print it because it is still located in the subshell.

After `done` (outside subshell), back in the parent shell, the line 77 prints `WYNIK` value, unmodified: empty string.

Comment: Not just `| while`, but **all** pipelines, unless the `lastpipe` flag is enabled (and prerequisites for its use are met). Even if you're piping to an external command, a subshell is forked off for a moment before it `exec`s that external command.

Comment: true, I tried to explain his script. I'll modify my answer. I do not know about `lastpipe` and prerequisites. thx!